# Solving the Fractional Fourier Integral Transform of $e^{j \omega_{0} t}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-transform, complex-integration

I want to solve the integral:

\begin{align}
 F_{\alpha}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot \sqrt{1 - j \text{cot}(\alpha)}  \cdot e^{j \frac{1}{2} \text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2} } \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-j \text{csc}(\alpha) \omega t + j \frac{1}{2} \text{cot}(\alpha)t^{2}  } e^{ j \omega_{0} t}   dt
\end{align}

where $j$ is the imaginary number. The problem is, the integral I get is not the answer I am expecting.

---

**Worked Solution:**

Combining the exponents gives us:
\begin{align}
F_{\alpha}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot \sqrt{1 - j \text{cot}(\alpha)}  \cdot e^{j \frac{1}{2} \text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2} } \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{- \frac{1}{2} \left[ -j \text{cot}(\alpha)t^{2} + 2j( \omega\text{csc}(\alpha) - \omega_{0} )  t  \right]} dt
\end{align}
Completing the square gives us:
\begin{align}
F_{\alpha}(\omega) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot \sqrt{1 - j \text{cot}(\alpha)}  \cdot e^{j \frac{1}{2} \text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2} } \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left[ -j\text{cot}(\alpha) \left( t + \frac{\omega_{0} - \omega \text{csc}(\alpha)}{\text{cot}(\alpha)} \right)^{2} + j \frac{\left( \omega \text{csc}(\alpha) - \omega_{0} \right)^{2}}{\text{cot}(\alpha)} \right] } dt \\
F_{\alpha}(\omega) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot \sqrt{1 - j \text{cot}(\alpha)}  \cdot e^{j \frac{1}{2} \text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2} } e^{-j \frac{1}{2}  \frac{\left( \omega \text{csc}(\alpha) - \omega_{0} \right)^{2}}{\text{cot}(\alpha)}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left[ -j\text{cot}(\alpha) \left( t + \frac{\omega_{0} - \omega \text{csc}(\alpha)}{\text{cot}(\alpha)} \right)^{2} \right] } dt \end{align}
Now we let $z = t + \frac{\omega_{0} - \omega \text{csc}(\alpha)}{\text{cot}(\alpha)} $, which means $dz = dt$, and the bounds don't change. This means we have:
\begin{align}
F_{\alpha}(\omega) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot \sqrt{1 - j \text{cot}(\alpha)}  \cdot e^{j \frac{1}{2} \text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2} } e^{-j \frac{1}{2}  \frac{\left( \omega \text{csc}(\alpha) - \omega_{0} \right)^{2}}{\text{cot}(\alpha)}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j \frac{1}{2} \text{cot}(\alpha) z^{2} } dz 
\end{align}
Well this is just a Gaussian integral, so we have:
\begin{align}
F_{\alpha}(\omega) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot \sqrt{1 - j \text{cot}(\alpha)}  \cdot e^{j \frac{1}{2} \text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2} } e^{-j \frac{1}{2}  \frac{\left( \omega \text{csc}(\alpha) - \omega_{0} \right)^{2}}{\text{cot}(\alpha)}} \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{-j \text{cot}(\alpha)}} \\
F_{\alpha}(\omega) &= \sqrt{ \frac{ 1 - j \text{cot}(\alpha)}{-j \text{cot}(\alpha)} }  \cdot e^{j \frac{1}{2} \text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2} } e^{-j \frac{1}{2}  \frac{\left( \omega \text{csc}(\alpha) - \omega_{0} \right)^{2}}{\text{cot}(\alpha)}} 
\end{align}
Now we will work on simplifiying this expression. We start with the radical:
\begin{align}
F_{\alpha}(\omega) &= \sqrt{ 1 + j \text{tan}(\alpha) }  \cdot e^{j \frac{1}{2} \text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2} } e^{-j \frac{1}{2}  \frac{\left( \omega \text{csc}(\alpha) - \omega_{0} \right)^{2}}{\text{cot}(\alpha)}} 
\end{align}
Now we combine the exponentials:
\begin{align}
F_{\alpha}(\omega) &= \sqrt{ 1 + j \text{tan}(\alpha) }  \cdot e^{j \frac{1}{2} \left[ \text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2} -  \frac{\left( \omega \text{csc}(\alpha) - \omega_{0} \right)^{2}}{\text{cot}(\alpha)} \right]} 
\end{align}
Now lets expand the exponent:
\begin{align}
\text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2} -  \frac{\left( \omega \text{csc}(\alpha) - \omega_{0} \right)^{2}}{\text{cot}(\alpha)} & = \text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2} - \frac{1}{\text{cot}(\alpha)} \cdot \left( \omega^{2} \text{csc}^{2}(\alpha) - 2 \omega_{0} \omega \text{csc}(\alpha) + \omega_{0}^{2}  \right)\\
 &= \frac{\text{cot}^{2}(\alpha) - \text{csc}^{2}(\alpha)}{\text{cot}(\alpha)} \omega^{2} + 2 \frac{\text{csc}(\alpha)}{\text{cot}(\alpha)} \omega_{0} \omega - \frac{1}{\text{cot}(\alpha)} \omega_{0}^{2} 
\end{align}
Since $\text{cot}(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\text{tan}(\alpha)} = \frac{\text{cos}(\alpha)}{\text{sin}(\alpha)}$, and $\text{csc}(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\text{sin}(\alpha)}$, we have:
\begin{align}
 &= \left( \text{cot}(\alpha) - \text{tan}(\alpha) \right) \omega^{2} + 2 \text{sec}(\alpha) \omega_{0} \omega - \text{tan}(\alpha) \omega_{0}^{2} \\
 &= -(\omega^{2} + \omega_{0}^{2}) \text{tan}(\alpha)  + 2 \text{sec}(\alpha) \omega_{0} \omega + \text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2}  \\
\end{align}
So we have:
\begin{align}
 \boxed{ F_{\alpha}(\omega) = \sqrt{ 1 + j \text{tan}(\alpha) }  \cdot e^{j\frac{1}{2} \text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2}} e^{-j \frac{1}{2} (\omega^{2} + \omega_{0}^{2}) \text{tan}(\alpha) + j \text{sec}(\alpha) \omega_{0} \omega} }
\end{align}

---

**The Problem:**

According to the paper "The Fractional Fourier Transform and Time-Frequency Representations" by Luis B Almeida, the answer should be:

\begin{align}
 \boxed{ F_{\alpha}(\omega) = \sqrt{ 1 + j \text{tan}(\alpha) }  e^{-j \frac{1}{2} (\omega^{2} + \omega_{0}^{2}) \text{tan}(\alpha) + j \text{sec}(\alpha) \omega_{0} \omega} }
\end{align}

In other words, my answer has an extra $e^{-j\frac{1}{2} \text{cot}(\alpha) \omega^{2}}$ term.

---

**Question:**

What have I done wrong? Am I correct, or is the paper incorrect?

---

**Edit 1:** I have tried plugging it into Mathematica, but it is of no help, even after trying all the simplify commands.

The Mathematica Answer:

```
(0.707107 E^((0. + 0.5 I) w^2 Cot[a] - (0. + 0.5 I) (1. v - 1. wCsc[a])^2 Tan[a]) Sqrt[1 - I Cot[a]])/Sqrt[(0. - 0.5 I) Cot[a]]
```

which is different from everyone's....

---

**Edit 2:** Here is another twist in the saga.

In the paper, it says that Almeida's result holds if $\alpha - \frac{pi}{2} \neq n \cdot pi$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

However, when $\alpha = n \cdot \pi + \frac{pi}{2} = \frac{2n+1}{2} \cdot \pi$, then $\text{cot}(\alpha) = \text{cot}\left( \frac{2n+1}{2} \cdot \pi \right) = 0$, so that extra complex exponential term is 1, which makes the my results agree with Almeida's.

What in the world??

Comment: Are you using the same definition of the factional Fourier transform that they are? Not everyone uses the same definitions for things and it can cause discrepancies like this.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes I am, In the paper, "Introduction to the Fractional Fourier Transform and its Applications" by Haldun M. Ozaktas and M. Alper Kutay, they get the same answer as in the Almeida paper (so I am wrong twice...). You can see it here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.64.6449&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: You combined the 2 exponentials... and afterwards you still have that first exponential in the final answer... looks like you forgot to remove it.

Comment: @KlaasvanAarsen I am not following you...Sorry, staring at one's own work can be hard sometimes. Hence why reviewers/editors have jobs haha :-P let me take another look...

Comment: You probably just need a good night's sleep. Tomorrow the answer will stare you in the face, and you won't understand why you didn't see it. ;)